# Can unruptured brain aneurysm symptoms come and go?

Tags: neurology, brain, symptoms

Lets say a person has many symptoms of a unruptured brain aneurysm, but they're rather subtle, and seem to change from one symptom to another. They come and go. Is that possible? Or, if they were legit, would they all stay the same, with the same level of intensity? Lets say, the only constant thus far is a slight weakness in the left leg, and arm (which is always differing and fluctuating).